# Git replacing current remote branch with master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, github-pages

I feel like I know how to do it, but I can't do it.

I am trying to create github pages. On remote origin I have 2 branches: master and gh-pages.

I accidentally updated remote gh-pages with update I don't want; I want my remote gh-pages to look exactly like remote master or local master. (My local master is up-to-date with remote master). The problem is, when I try to pull gh-pages, it conflicts with my local master.

How can I replace remote branch gh-pages with either remote/local master? (granted the current remote gh-pages conflicts with remote/local master)

```
Blah-Air:SomeBranch blablah$ git pull origin gh-pages
remote: Counting objects: 15, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Total 15 (delta 1), reused 15 (delta 1), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (15/15), done.
From https://github.com/SomeGitHub/SomeBranch
 * branch            gh-pages   -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      gh-pages   -> origin/gh-pages
Auto-merging index.html
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in index.html
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

^ As you can see, I need to fix the conflict, but I wasn't sure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you probably shouldn't be developing on your local `gh-pages` branch if you want the remote to always be in sync with the `master` branch. I feel like I'd be making the same mistake as you did if I didn't develop on a different branch.

But to get out of this situation you can use `git reset --hard HEAD^` to return to the parent commit and then force push the branch that points to the correct commit with `git push origin gh-pages -f`. If you'd like to keep that commit on your local `gh-pages`, then try force pushing your local `master` (which is supposedly already at the right commit) to your remote `gh-pages`.